# Event Waitlists Showing Credit Card Fields and no Price Sets

Tags: civievent, civicontribute

I am testing the events waitlist functionality for CiviEvents. I have followed the steps in the document and I can see the waitlist feature is successfully enabled on an event. However, when we go to register as a person for the waitlist it is not showing the price set of the tickets options and also showing a mandatory credit card details. Does a person have to input their card details when adding to a waitlist. Where do these card details go as they do not show in the payments and seem to simply disappear. Also is there a way to disable the requirement for a card. Thanks. Any clarifications would be great.